# Receiving "Run-time error '1004': Microsoft Excel cannot paste the data." on occasion running macro in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I use a template sheet with a macro that opens a selected text file, copies and pastes the information into an Excel sheet tab, closes the text file. Repeating 8 times (8 total text files) then performs a text to column as well as a pivot refresh. While performing the action of opening the file then copying and pasting the information, I will sometimes receive the error in the title. It is not every time but it is fairly often. Below is the code being used in VBA.

```
Sub FormatTemplate()

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 1")).Select
    Selection.Delete
    Range("A1").Select

    Dim my_FileName As Variant
    my_FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename
    If my_FileName <> False Then
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=my_FileName
    End If
    Cells.Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.Close
    Windows("Template.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    
    my_FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename
    If my_FileName <> False Then
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=my_FileName
    End If
    Cells.Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.Close
    Windows("Template.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    
    my_FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename
    If my_FileName <> False Then
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=my_FileName
    End If
    Cells.Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.Close
    Windows("Template.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    
    my_FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename
    If my_FileName <> False Then
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=my_FileName
    End If
    Cells.Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.Close
    Windows("Template.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("4").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    my_FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename
    If my_FileName <> False Then
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=my_FileName
    End If
    Cells.Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.Close
    Windows("Template.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("5").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    my_FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename
    If my_FileName <> False Then
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=my_FileName
    End If
    Cells.Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.Close
    Windows("Template.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("6").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    my_FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename
    If my_FileName <> False Then
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=my_FileName
    End If
    Cells.Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.Close
    Windows("Template.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("7").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    
    my_FileName = Application.GetOpenFilename
    If my_FileName <> False Then
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=my_FileName
    End If
    Cells.Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.Close
    Windows("Template.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("8").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    Sheets("1").Select
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 2), Array(16, 1), Array(21, 1), Array(26, 1), Array(34, 1), _
        Array(52, 1), Array(57, 1), Array(69, 1), Array(73, 1), Array(82, 1), Array(86, 1), Array( _
        91, 1), Array(97, 1), Array(98, 1), Array(100, 1), Array(110, 1), Array(115, 1), Array(117, _
        1), Array(119, 1), Array(121, 1), Array(133, 1), Array(141, 1), Array(148, 1), Array(154, 1 _
        ), Array(163, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Range("A7:W7").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$7:$Y$5000").AutoFilter Field:=21, Criteria1:="=ZX-101" _
        , Operator:=xlAnd
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$7:$Y$5000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=4*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    Columns("I:I").Select
    Selection.Style = "Comma"
    Range("A7").Select
    
    Sheets("2").Select
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 2), Array(16, 1), Array(21, 1), Array(26, 1), Array(34, 1), _
        Array(52, 1), Array(57, 1), Array(69, 1), Array(73, 1), Array(82, 1), Array(86, 1), Array( _
        91, 1), Array(97, 1), Array(98, 1), Array(100, 1), Array(110, 1), Array(115, 1), Array(117, _
        1), Array(119, 1), Array(121, 1), Array(133, 1), Array(141, 1), Array(148, 1), Array(154, 1 _
        ), Array(163, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Range("A7:W7").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$7:$Y$5000").AutoFilter Field:=21, Criteria1:="=ZX-101" _
        , Operator:=xlAnd
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$7:$Y$5000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=4*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    Columns("I:I").Select
    Selection.Style = "Comma"
    Range("A7").Select
    
    Sheets("3").Select
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 2), Array(16, 1), Array(21, 1), Array(26, 1), Array(34, 1), _
        Array(52, 1), Array(57, 1), Array(69, 1), Array(73, 1), Array(82, 1), Array(86, 1), Array( _
        91, 1), Array(97, 1), Array(98, 1), Array(100, 1), Array(110, 1), Array(115, 1), Array(117, _
        1), Array(119, 1), Array(121, 1), Array(133, 1), Array(141, 1), Array(148, 1), Array(154, 1 _
        ), Array(163, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Range("A7:W7").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$7:$Y$5000").AutoFilter Field:=21, Criteria1:="=ZX-101" _
        , Operator:=xlAnd
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$7:$Y$5000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=4*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    Columns("I:I").Select
    Selection.Style = "Comma"
    Range("A7").Select
    
    Sheets("4").Select
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 2), Array(16, 1), Array(21, 1), Array(26, 1), Array(34, 1), _
        Array(52, 1), Array(57, 1), Array(69, 1), Array(73, 1), Array(82, 1), Array(86, 1), Array( _
        91, 1), Array(97, 1), Array(98, 1), Array(100, 1), Array(110, 1), Array(115, 1), Array(117, _
        1), Array(119, 1), Array(121, 1), Array(133, 1), Array(141, 1), Array(148, 1), Array(154, 1 _
        ), Array(163, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Range("A7:W7").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$7:$Y$5000").AutoFilter Field:=21, Criteria1:="=ZX-101" _
        , Operator:=xlAnd
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$7:$Y$5000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=4*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    Columns("I:I").Select
    Selection.Style = "Comma"
    Range("A7").Select
    
    Sheets("5").Select
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 2), Array(16, 1), Array(21, 1), Array(26, 1), Array(34, 1), _
        Array(52, 1), Array(57, 1), Array(69, 1), Array(73, 1), Array(82, 1), Array(86, 1), Array( _
        91, 1), Array(97, 1), Array(98, 1), Array(100, 1), Array(110, 1), Array(115, 1), Array(117, _
        1), Array(119, 1), Array(121, 1), Array(133, 1), Array(141, 1), Array(148, 1), Array(154, 1 _
        ), Array(163, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Range("A7:W7").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$7:$Y$5000").AutoFilter Field:=21, Criteria1:="=ZX-101" _
        , Operator:=xlAnd
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$7:$Y$5000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=4*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    Columns("I:I").Select
    Selection.Style = "Comma"
    Range("A7").Select
    
    Sheets("6").Select
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 2), Array(16, 1), Array(21, 1), Array(26, 1), Array(34, 1), _
        Array(52, 1), Array(57, 1), Array(69, 1), Array(73, 1), Array(82, 1), Array(86, 1), Array( _
        91, 1), Array(97, 1), Array(98, 1), Array(100, 1), Array(110, 1), Array(115, 1), Array(117, _
        1), Array(119, 1), Array(121, 1), Array(133, 1), Array(141, 1), Array(148, 1), Array(154, 1 _
        ), Array(163, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Range("A7:W7").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$7:$Y$5000").AutoFilter Field:=21, Criteria1:="=ZX-101" _
        , Operator:=xlAnd
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$7:$Y$5000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=4*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    Columns("I:I").Select
    Selection.Style = "Comma"
    Range("A7").Select
    
    Sheets("7").Select
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 2), Array(16, 1), Array(21, 1), Array(26, 1), Array(34, 1), _
        Array(52, 1), Array(57, 1), Array(69, 1), Array(73, 1), Array(82, 1), Array(86, 1), Array( _
        91, 1), Array(97, 1), Array(98, 1), Array(100, 1), Array(110, 1), Array(115, 1), Array(117, _
        1), Array(119, 1), Array(121, 1), Array(133, 1), Array(141, 1), Array(148, 1), Array(154, 1 _
        ), Array(163, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Range("A7:W7").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$7:$Y$5000").AutoFilter Field:=21, Criteria1:="=ZX-101" _
        , Operator:=xlAnd
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$7:$Y$5000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=4*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    Columns("I:I").Select
    Selection.Style = "Comma"
    Range("A7").Select
    
    Sheets("8").Select
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 2), Array(16, 1), Array(21, 1), Array(26, 1), Array(34, 1), _
        Array(52, 1), Array(57, 1), Array(69, 1), Array(73, 1), Array(82, 1), Array(86, 1), Array( _
        91, 1), Array(97, 1), Array(98, 1), Array(100, 1), Array(110, 1), Array(115, 1), Array(117, _
        1), Array(119, 1), Array(121, 1), Array(133, 1), Array(141, 1), Array(148, 1), Array(154, 1 _
        ), Array(163, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
    Range("A7:W7").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$7:$Y$5000").AutoFilter Field:=21, Criteria1:="=ZX-101" _
        , Operator:=xlAnd
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$7:$Y$5000").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=4*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    Columns("I:I").Select
    Selection.Style = "Comma"
    Range("A7").Select
    
    Sheets("1").Select
    Range("A7").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("All PRIN").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    
    Sheets("2").Select
    Range("A7").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("All PRIN").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
       Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    
    Sheets("3").Select
    Range("A7").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("All PRIN").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    
    Sheets("4").Select
    Range("A7").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("All PRIN").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    
    Sheets("5").Select
    Range("A7").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("All PRIN").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    
    Sheets("6").Select
    Range("A7").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("All PRIN").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
       Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    
    Sheets("7").Select
    Range("A7").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("All PRIN").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    
    Sheets("8").Select
    Range("A7").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("All PRIN").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("AA1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotCache.Refresh

End Sub
```

Hitting debug highlights one of the `ActiveSheet.Paste` lines

I have attempted different ways of copying and pasting, as well as changing how the macro goes about opening and closing the text files. Looked up and applied different answers that I found through StackOverflow and none seemed to resolve the issue.

Comment: Have you tried splitting the copy/paste? Here https://stackoverflow.com/a/76794690/18247317 how I managed to have it in Excel (look at the Update)

Comment: Might or might not be the cause of your problem, but you might want to see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/11318818) particularly section starting "A common (bad) piece of code is to open a book, get some data then close again". Also you might try manually copying and pasting from / to the same worksheets to see what problem(s) you experience?

Comment: Would recommend reviewing this post and applying the guidelines outlined there.  It will reduce the size of your code and make it more robust.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: Also you can copy values between ranges without using copy/paste - plenty of examples here on SO.