# Excel Range Select results in Range Class Failed

Tags: excel, vba

I use range(NN:NN).select all the time.  I know .select is frowned upon, but I use it.  I wrote some VBA code recently to track and manage my Wordle games and I use range.select throughout the code with no problems. In this one instance I get a failure - Run-Time error '1004': Select method of Range class failed.

Screenshot of the portion of code with the error

[image: 1]

I tried selecting the Worksheet specifically above this range.select line even though the code in this section has been in that Worksheet all along.  I searched for the error '1004' online and in this forum but it is apparently a vague error.

Comment: Please don't post code as a picture, include the code in our question. You may also have a look onto https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: Great suggestion, will do!  Thank you Shrotter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Note:*** It's important to qualify `Range` reference with sheet object. eg. `Sheets("..").Range("..")`

- Assumes `CommandButton2` is a control on a sheet named `Sheet1`.
- The first line makes `Tracker` sheet as the activesheet.
- As `CommandButton2_Click` is in `Sheet1` module, the 2nd line is equalient to `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("N2:S1").Select`. Selecting a range on a non-activesheet throws 1004 error.

```
    Sheets("Tracker").Select
    ...
    Range("N2:S1").Select
```

- It's worth to read: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba/10717999#10717999)
- The section of `Delete last guess played ..` can be revised as below w/o `Select`.

```vb
    Sheets("Tracker").Range(PasteRange).Offset(0, GuessCount).ClearContents
    With Sheets("...") ' modify as needed
        .Range("N2", .Range("N2").End(xldow)).ClearContents
    End With
```

Comment: Thanks taller!  I used your suggestion and it worked perfectly (after correcting "x1dow" to "x1down")  ;-)  Also I do appreciate the link to avoid using Select.

Answer (score 0):

try an break up the `.Select` bit into a separate function, for example (in PowerPoint)

```
Sub sHseLect(sH As PowerPoint.Shape)
    sH.Select
End Sub
```

in your case it would be something like:

```
Sub rngSeLect(rng As Excel.Range)
    rng.Select
End Sub
```

I have managed in this way to use `Select` (when it is needed because I have to access some features available only in the Ribbon) without any failure. Even when it was being called thousands of times.

The common explanation you will find is that VBA will proceed with its calculations and, when it is time to do the selection, it will fail because it had not finished to deal with the previous tasks. Just like for [Copy/Paste](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76794690/18247317), breaking this function from the main procedure will force VBA to complete all its duties.